# Convention for LaTeX links

Tags: latex

How do I link to another section, or subsection of my LaTeX document?  What is the conventional format for such links, to write them like [link name], or to do them like webpage hyperlinks?

Answer (score 10):

Linking to another section requires some additional markup from your part. The commands to use are:

- \label{identifier} - *Creates a label which can later be **referenced** by the following two commands*
- \ref{identifier} - *LaTeX replaces this markup with the **number** of the section/subsection/figure/table/theorem in which the label-identifier is defined.*
- \pageref{identifier} -  *LaTeX replaces this markup with the **page number** of the section/subsection/figure/table/theorem in which the label-identifier is defined.*

So, to create a reference to another section in your text, say "see section X.Y on page Z", you write

```
\label{mySection} % Put this inside your section

see section \ref{mySection} on page \pageref{mySection}"
```

Note: When you are cross-referencing, make sure to compile multiple times until you no longer get any warnings.

Comment: This is all very true and useful, but does not (by default) create links in the document

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in addition to using `\label`, `\ref` and `\pageref`, use the package [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).